# Using If and Else with razor (model => model.Var) expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using [GridMVC](http://gridmvc.codeplex.com) in my project, This code Show me `0` or `1` :

```
columns.Add(model => model.ETAT)
                            .Filterable(true)
                            .Titled("Etat")
                            .Sortable(true);
```

`Etat` can have `only two value Zero or One`. So Instead of Showing 0 or 1 I want to display `good IF value it's 1, (etat = 1) ELSE show bad( etat = 0)`.

[image]

How to do it ?
Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a ETATDisplay to my ViewModel so that it does the calculation on that backend.

something like

```
public class myViewModel 
{
    public int ETAT {get;set;}
    public string ETATDisplay 
    {
        get { return ETAT == 1 ? "Good" : "Bad";}
    }
}
```

Then it just should be the following on the view

```
columns.Add(model => model.ETATDisplay)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the following

```
columns.Add(model => (model.ETAT== 0) ? "bad" :"good")
```

Comment: `Expression 'model => IIF((model.ETAT == Convert(0)), "bad", "good")'`.  not supported by grid any other way ?

Comment: I never used `GridMVC` but try `IIF(!model.ETAT.Value, "bad", "good")`

Comment: Like this : `columns.Add(model => IIF(!model.ETAT.Value, "bad", "good"))` ? it's not accepted I got error

Comment: And why he's trying to convert(0) Etat got decimal Type and 0 is Decimal they have same type

Comment: your datatype is BIT?

Comment: Etat is Decimal `public Nullable<decimal> ETAT { get; set; }`

Comment: @Chlebta try changing to an `int` then do this `columns.Add(model => (model.ETAT== 0) ? "bad" :"good")`

Comment: Thank's meda, but changing type need lot of works because I work on a ready database I'dont have permission to edite type. I'm gonna use Nathan Fisher solution, thank you so much